# Are politicians attempting to destroy tenure?

Tags: professorship, united-states, tenure-track, policy

Apparently, Iowa's politicians intend to enrich the tenure experience by annual [gladiatorial games](http://academeblog.org/2015/04/21/culling-the-iowa-faculty/) at state schools, regardless of tenure:

1. those being evaluated below some threshold shall be terminated, and
2. after (1), the 5 remaining lowest scoring professors will be put to a public student vote, and the one with the least student support shall be terminated.

The source looks legit - blog of the AAUP. I'm not sure if this is enacted, or proposed (I think proposed). I'm also not entirely sure how to link this to an answerable question fit for Academia.SE, but maybe:

- Is this a joke I didn't get, or is it true?
- Is it part of a broader wave?
- Does this contradict any case law, or is being fought already somehow; or will professors just have to live with it?

If this is true, and stands in Iowa, to be worried for the US at large one just has to look at how quality of life legislation spread like a wild fire once enacted in one place.

Comment: [Full text of the bill as proposed by Mark Chelgren](http://coolice.legis.iowa.gov/Cool-ICE/default.asp?Category=billinfo&Service=Billbook&menu=true&ga=86&hbill=SF64).

Comment: When student evaluations of teaching allow open comments, they often revel sexist, racist, and homophobic attitudes. While I am not a lawyer, terminating someone for potentially "protected" reasons, is likely illegal.

Comment: To be fair, that's pretty much how politicians get to keep / lose their jobs. Though it seems like a rather bad idea to apply that system to academia...

Comment: @Moriarty The difference as you know is that politicians try to determine what to do whereas academics try to determine what is true. Representative democracy may work for the former, but certainly not the latter. If 70% of the population doesn't believe in smoking, you can outlaw it. If 70% of the population doesn't believe in evolution, it doesn't do any good to pretend it is false.

Comment: This is a particularly cynical interpretation of [democratisation of universities](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/feb/03/battle-to-democratise-universities-student-protest).

Comment: Interestingly, Senate File 64 always seems to die: https://legiscan.com/IA/research/SF64.

Comment: @user6726: I admit ignorance: what is "in recess" wrt to suggested legislation? Temporary suspension of discussion? I've only ever heard the term wrt politicians ("after the recess, senate...")

Comment: I don't know what that means there: I was referring to the amusing fact that when the same number was used in the previous 3 general assemblies, it died in subcommittee. Oh, I found the mouse-over -- it means the session is in recess.

Comment: @gnometorule It means the Iowa Senate is in recess right now, so the bill's not being worked on at the moment.

Comment: Yikes. The language of the bill is very (scaringly) vague. "Criteria" and "rating system." Conservative politicians are en masse pushing for MOOCs and a dismantling of the higher education system. It's started a bit in Canada and many professors I have close relationships with are incredibly worried about the future of academia in Canada. The vague language makes it seem like the rating system and criteria could be influenced heavily from the outside. (Do you teach evolution? That's a paddlin'.) I have known a few professors who honestly did not deserve tenure but the vast majority...

Comment: ... work hard and are very committed to their craft as researchers and teachers. At the primary school level, I understand addressing the issue of tenure. There are many, many horrible teachers who hardly understand their subject material. That is not an easily corrected issue as it is very much a systemic one. The issue is multifaceted and getting rid of bad tenured teachers doesn't even begin to fix the issue there. However, trying to remove tenure at the collegiate level is not doing anyone any favors.

Comment: @Corvus  Re "academics try to determine what is true", that seems (in my experience, anyway) to be mostly true in STEM fields, though even there you'll find the occasional academic who'll ignore facts in order to keep riding his/her particular hobbyhorse.  In the humanities & social sciences, the hobbyhorse riders seem to be the majority.

Comment: Conservative politicians would like to dismember higher education because an educated electorate is their biggest problem. Look at places like Pakistan and Afghanistan. Education? Not so much. And conservatives do *really well* there. Keep 'em stupid, feed 'em bullsh*t, and keep getting elected - a politicians paradise. :-)

Comment: @StrongBad Wow, really? O.o We have had lecture evaluations with open comment fields for decades now, and I don't recall reading something like that, ever.

Comment: @Raphael I think this [interactive chart](http://benschmidt.org/profGender/) makes the point about sexism.

Comment: @StrongBad Interesting, thanks! (Given the low incidence of most words, the room for interpretation is probably limited, and I'd like to group by synonyms, but interesting in any case.) Nevertheless, this does not offset the fact that the official, standardized lecture evaluations at my (German, STEM-focused) university do not display this, at least not as openly as your first comment suggests. I'd be interested in word counts, though.

Comment: Welcome to the Hunger Games (the crowd roars)!

Comment: @Miguel: Funny you mention that! I found this on the facebook page of a friend (professor at Vancouver) who shared it with the same remark. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Proposals to "reform" or end tenure are not new—they have been going around for several decades at least (as I remember such stories when I was an undergraduate in the 1990's).

This is not yet enacted legislation—it is merely a proposal that, as far as I can tell, probably has not even had any hearings yet. As such, I would suspect that such a bill would be shot down in committee, as the proposed methods would probably violate at least some sort of labor laws, as the faculty would in effect be judged by students with whom they have never interacted. Such "popularity contests" would pretty much dry up any opportunities for faculty recruitment. (Who would want to work at such a school?)

Comment: The point that students would judge professors that didn't teach them is excellent; so at least in this form it seems unlikely to be constitutional. As someone -  other than you apparently :) -  who's never seen such idiotic attempts, I'm still worried that a somewhat mollified version could pass. I +1ed of course; just my 5 cents.

Comment: It seems overwhelmingly likely that this is just political grandstanding -- it's too absurd to be a serious proposal. But in any event, student evaluations are a terrible metric to use for this purpose because they closely reflect expected course grade -- and thus incentivize faculty not to make their classes demanding. If jobs depended on a metric like this, you could be sure that any remaining vestiges of actual content would evaporate and rampant grade inflation would follow.

Comment: The inanity is not limited to politicians. Several years ago, the Vice-President for Academic Affairs at my school proposed that all faculty scoring below average (whatever he meant by that) on course evaluations should be terminated. He became almost apoplectic when one of my math colleagues informed him that he was proposing to eliminate half the faculty. Much as we would like to believe otherwise, we are not living in a higher education version of Lake Woebegone.

Comment: @ChrisLeary in any individual round it would be possible for the number of terminated faculty to be much less than half (depending on the definition of average).  Assuming that the first round of cuts eliminated all the "bad" faculty and the university only hired "good" replacement faculty, subsequent rounds would necessarily eliminate "good" faculty - which probably does not bother some people too much.

Comment: @ChrisLeary I'm told that our administration once proposed something like this as a requirement for tenure. When the faculty senate and such pointed out that student evaluations correlate very poorly with learning outcomes, the administration engaged in classic bureacracythink: they suggested lowering the bar from top half of a meaningless metric to top 80% of a meaningless metric. At least the flip of a coin was being replaced by the roll of a die, I guess. Fortunately none of this was ever enacted.

Comment: @ChrisLeary - apparently the qualifications for being promoted into an academic vice-presidency do not require mastery of basic statistics. :-)

Comment: This bill won't be passed this session at least. The Iowa state legislature has a cut-off date that prevents bills from being considered if they haven't passed a committee by then. [I think we're past it, if I'm reading this right](https://www.legis.iowa.gov/docs/Schedules/SessionTimetable.pdf)

Comment: Who would want to work at such a school?  Maybe someone who's actually good at relating to students and getting along with them.  You don't even know how many teachers I had, both in public school and then later at college, who failed *badly* at this most fundamental of all qualifications!

Answer (score 8):

The [follow-up post](http://academeblog.org/2015/04/22/culling-the-faculty-part-ii/) to the aforelinked post mentioned above answers most of your questions. Specifically:

- The bill is not a joke, it was actually [submitted as proposed legislation](https://www.legis.iowa.gov/docs/Published/LGI/86/SF64.pdf?hc_location=ufi).
- The proposed bill, like many before it, is a very clearly a Bad Idea™. To quote from the blog:

  > The absolute nuttiness of the bill is the best defense against its ever becoming law. Iowa, though, has other protections. Katherine Tachau, President of the University of Iowa AAUP chapter, informs me that this dead-on-arrival bill was intercepted by the Iowa Senate Education Committee chair, a professor at Iowa State, who sent it to a subcommittee chaired by another ally of education. Tachau writes, “I’m inclined to think that this bill belongs to the large category of ill-informed bills on any number of subjects with no chance of passage with which the records of all legislatures are replete.” I agree.

  It does not appear that this bill has any chance whatsoever of actually becoming legislation.
- Unfortunately, this bill is not alone; there are other examples of the teaching professions being attached through legislation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the follow-up blog post out, and I hope that author is right in his opinion of it having no chance of passage (the opinion supported by relevant people involved in legislating in Iowa). I agree that one must be vigilant though. Crazy bills have managed to pass, and it only takes one precedent for the case law machine to go into overdrive.

Comment: So if it doesn't die quickly, academics need to shout, hard.  Not only in Iowa, but across the USA and internationally.

Comment: As I understand the workings of Iowa's legislature (poorly), it is passed all deadlines for this year. Rather than shouting, we should oppose rationally.

Comment: Then there was this bill that should make Pi 3.2 by law... but that was in Michigan, I think!?

Comment: Neither life, liberty, nor property are safe while the legislature is in session... Just sayin'...

Comment: @Alexander - I believe you're thinking of [the Indiana Pi bill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill), an early testament to the brilliance and fortitude of the legislature of the Hoosier State (whose recent actions have been so much in the news of late). Sadly the legislators of 1897 were not made of stern enough stuff and it was never enacted into law, and thus even to this day students at such great seats of learning such as Purdue and Notre Dame must still labor to memorize long lists of the digits of pi rather than the much simpler value of 3.2. What a shame, what a waste... :-)